# Is that a bug between `xymatrix`, the `input` command and .sty file?

Tags: packages, input, xy-pic, debugging

I have a problem compiling the following document.

First, I have a file `macros.sty` that consists of :

```
\newcommand{\test}{
\xymatrix@R=0mm{x}
}
```

Then, I have an auxiliary file `out.aux` that consists of :

```
\test
```

Finally, the main file is :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{macros}
\begin{document}
\input{out.aux}
\end{document}
```

The error message is :

```
./out.aux:1: Undefined control sequence.
\xymatrix@R ->\Addop@@ 
                   \xymatrixrowsep@ \dimen@ii
```

*Note that if you remove the `R=0mm`, the problem no longer holds.*

Is that a bug ?

It is very strange because I remember to have already used a command similar to `\test` in an `input` file without any problem.

Does it come from my distribution ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `.sty` files are read with an implicit `\makeatletter` command, so your input is interpreted as the command `\xymatrix@R` and not as `\xymatrix` followed by `@`. Either write

```
\makeatother
\newcommand{\test}{\xymatrix@R=0mm{x}}
\makeatletter
```

or move the definition of `\test` to a file that you load with `\input` and not with `\usepackage`.

Comment: Clear and nice answer ! Apart from this @-matter, what's the difference between `\input` and `\usepackage` ? Should I prefer `\usepackage` for my commands ?

Comment: Your idea works but I dont understand why there is no problem if I execute directly in the .tex file the command `\test`.

Comment: @Colas I get the same error both with `\input` and writing `\test` directly in the file. I'd recommend `\input` for your macros.