# Unknown compilation error with xymatrix

Tags: xymatrix

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\test}{\xymatrix@M=-.3pt@=10pt}
\newcommand{\testt}[2][1]{\ar@[|(1)]@#1{-}[#2]}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&f=\test{
& \bullet \testt{dl} \testt{dr} \\
\bullet & & \circ }
&g=\test{
 & & \bullet \testt{dl}\testt{d}\testt{dr}\\
& \bullet & \bullet \testt{d} & \bullet \testt{d}\\
& & \circ & \circ }
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Please help!!!!!

related to this [Is that a bug between `xymatrix`, the `input` command and .sty file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31930/is-that-a-bug-between-xymatrix-the-input-command-and-sty-file) but solution not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just comment out `\makeatletter` (and `\makeatother`) since otherwise the `@` (and ordinary characters that follow them) become part of the macros. (This is sort of what the answer you link to is trying to say.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
%\makeatletter
\newcommand{\test}{\xymatrix@M=-.3pt@=10pt}
\newcommand{\testt}[2][1]{\ar@[|(1)]@#1{-}[#2]}
%\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&f=\test{
& \bullet \testt{dl} \testt{dr} \\
\bullet & & \circ }
&g=\test{
 & & \bullet \testt{dl}\testt{d}\testt{dr}\\
& \bullet & \bullet \testt{d} & \bullet \testt{d}\\
& & \circ & \circ }
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any possibility to work with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatoher` ??

Comment: @Newtolatex Why do you want to do that? Is there a reason why you wish to keep `\makeatletter` "switched on"?

Comment: Am using own cls and sty files there are more `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

Comment: @Newtolatex In cls and sty files, `\makeatletter` is  "switched on" automatically. Then you need to switch it of for the purpose of these command definitions. That is, inside a package you need `\makeatother
\newcommand{\test}{\xymatrix@M=-.3pt@=10pt}
\newcommand{\testt}[2][1]{\ar@[|(1)]@#1{-}[#2]}
\makeatletter`.

Comment: Great working fine!!!!